# Concatenation of two string in razor view

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an `cshtml` problem: i have this snippet:

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
               {
                <tr>
                <td>
                        <input class="myCell" type="text" name ="num"@i/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="myCell" type="text" name="client"@i/>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input class="myCell" type="date" name ="reception"@i/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="myCell" type="date" name="cloture"@i/>
                </td>
            </tr> 
               }
```

and i'd like to rename the first inputs `num0`, `client0`..... until the last inputs `num23`, `client23` ..., i try the snippet above but it didn't work.

Why the code didn't work? How can i fix it?

Comment: **How** didn't it work? What happened?

Comment: Read the generated source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to write

```
name="num@(i)"
```

The parentheses are necessary to prevent Razor from thinking it's an email address and ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the variable inside the double quotes and put it in parenthesis:

```
<input class="myCell" type="text" name ="num@(i)"/>
<input class="myCell" type="text" name="client@(i)"/>
...
```